# "called object is not a function" error - C

Tags: c, pointers, reference

```
int getSpeedOfMotorInPercent(int RPM)
{
    int speedOfMotor = (RPM/5000.0)*100;
    return speedOfMotor;
}

static char *test_GetSpeedOfMotor(int speedInPercent)
{
    mu_assert("error, RPM != 70%", speedInPercent == 70);
    return 0;
}

static char *run_all_tests(int RPM)
{
    mu_run_test(test_GetSpeedOfMotor(RPM));
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error "called object is not a function" on `mu_run_test(test_GetSpeedOfMotor(RPM));`

I tried removing the pointer of the function but then I get even more errors.

**EDIT:**

```
#define mu_assert(message, test) do { if (!(test)) return message; } while (0)
#define mu_run_test(test) do { char *message = test(); tests_run++; if (message) return message; } while (0)
 extern int tests_run;
```

this is the `mu_run_test` function. It is provided to me like that in the header file.

Comment: You haven't shown us the definition of `mu_run_test`. That is essential to answering this question. Could you provide it?

Comment: I'm betting mu_run_test does something like this
void mu_run_test(char* x)
{
   x()
}, trying to call the passed in char* as though it was a function pointer.

Comment: @MagnusHoff I updated the post with the `mu_run_test` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `test_GetSpeedOfMotor(RPM)` as `test` in the macro, which will result in this code:

```
char *message = test_GetSpeedOfMotor(RPM)();
```

Since you're probably using a test framework which you don't want to change, just remove the `RPM` parameter from the declaration of `test_GetSpeedOfMotor` function and use it like this:

```
int testRpmInPercent;

static char *test_GetSpeedOfMotor()
{
    mu_assert("error, RPM != 70%", testRpmInPercent == 70);
    return 0;
}

static char *run_all_tests(int RPM)
{
    testRpmInPercent = RPM;
    mu_run_test(test_GetSpeedOfMotor);
    return 0;
}
```

Then you'll have to find an other way of sharing the `RPM` value with the test function. Like a global variable or with whatever method the test framework has to offer.

If you're willing to change the test framework, I would modify that define to this (remove `()` after `test`):

```
#define mu_run_test(test) do { char *message = test; tests_run++; if (message) return message; } while (0)
```

Comment: I typically never user macros in this way, but wouldn't this just do the job

#define mu_run_test(test) do { char *message = test; tests_run++; if (message) return message; } while (0)

and calling it in the same way he did in the original question.

Comment: @SlxS: that was my proposal in my first post, but then I realized that the OP might be using an external test framework, which you don't want to patch like this.

Comment: I did the first suggestion - just removed the `()` in from the definition of the framework. That's not a problem. Thanks :)